# Why Twilio is not working? what does HTTP 400 Error mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, twilio

I'm taking the Python Udacity course, and since I'm new to programming my debugging skills are very low.
**I'm using python 3.5**
I've followed the instructions in the video and also the Twilio instructions.
I recieved my account_sid & auth_token as well as the Twilio phone number. Yet, the code doesn't work,
Here is the code(I put stars where it needs to be hidden):

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

account_sid = "{{ *** }}" # Your Account SID from www.twilio.com/console
auth_token  = "{{ *** }}"  # Your Auth Token from www.twilio.com/console

client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages.create(body="Hello from Me",
to="+1***",    # Replace with your phone number 
from_="+1***") # Replace with your Twilio number

print(message.sid)
```

and here is the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kd/pythonfiles/new.py", line 11, in <module>
    from_="+***") # Replace with your Twilio number
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/twilio/rest/resources/messages.py", line 122, in create
    return self.create_instance(kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/twilio/rest/resources/base.py", line 365, in create_instance
    data=transform_params(body))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/twilio/rest/resources/base.py", line 200, in request
    resp = make_twilio_request(method, uri, auth=self.auth, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/twilio/rest/resources/base.py", line 164, in make_twilio_request
    uri=resp.url, msg=message, code=code)
twilio.rest.exceptions.TwilioRestException: HTTP 400 error: 
[Finished in 0.6s with exit code 1]
```

I understand that a HTTP 400 error is related to my unit sending a bad signal. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

That code looks pretty good to me. The only thing I can think of is whether, when you fill in your Account SID and Auth Token, you leave the `{{` and `}}` in?

Those two lines should look like:

```
account_sid = "AC1234567890"
auth_token  = "fedcba0987654321"
```

when filled in with your credentials.

Let me know if that helps.